# How to attach script in tab created by gBrowser.addTab()?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create empty tab and inject a script file into it.

```
var wm = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
var browserEnumerator = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
var tabbrowser = browserEnumerator.getNext().gBrowser;
var newTab = tabbrowser.addTab("");
```

With pageMod i can attach file with

```
contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.9.1.min.js")],
```

How do i attach script for gBrowser created tab?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar to this except for existing tabs -- meaning you might have to tweak it a bit and listen to the `"load"` event for the `contentWindow` of the added tab:

setup attachWorker function:

```
let contentWorker=require("sdk/content/worker");

function attachWorker(contentWindow,options){    
    options.window = contentWindow;
    let worker = contentWorker.Worker(options);
    worker.once("detach", function detach() {
        worker.destroy();
    });
    return worker;
}
```

when a tab is available:

```
var browser=gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
var contentWindow=browser.contentWindow;
```

when `contentWindow` is loaded -- listen for `contentWindow` `'load'` (if applicable?):

```
var options={contentScriptFile:...};
attachWorker(contentWindow, options);
```

Documentation for content worker:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/content/worker.html

Code from `attachWorker()` is a slightly altered version of `Worker()` function from the sdk (available from within your jetpack addon package or [mozilla addon-sdk repository](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/lib/sdk)):
https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/tabs/worker.js

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Add-on SDK already, you can use the tabs module:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  tab.attach({
      contentScript:
        'document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";'
  });
});
```

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29